# why does python choose only the first statement?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print (' give me your name \n without any number ')
name=input('enter your name ')
print (name)
for i in name:
    if i == 1 or 2 or 3:
        print ('this name have number in it you failed ')
        print (i)       
    else:
        print ("you pass  ")
```

even if I entered the name with the number 1~3 or without it will choose the first statement why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: the `or` is not working as you think.  Try: `if i in (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: You actually have three problems: you're doing letter by letter checks but printing a verdict each time, you're testing against integers `1, 2, 3` instead of characters `'1', '2', '3'`, and your `or` logic isn't correct.